# Is there a way to revision all projects in a solution?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a solution with over 30 projects in it... Is there a quick and easy way of managing the build revision of all projects rather than editing the AssemblyInfo or Properties of each one?

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/

Comment: This is a  real lifesaver http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5851/Versioning-Controlled-Build

Comment: @cadrell0 I did say quick and easy! What's easy about establishing a CI server?

Comment: @daveL The installation isn't hard and it is automatic after that.  I haven't had to worry about versioning since we started using TeamCity.  Also, that is why I didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: @daveL do you want a good solution or a quick and easy one? Long term, CI is invaluable for many reasons.

Comment: I know the value of CI - but we don't use CI here so hey ho

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the past, I've followed the advice in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jjameson/archive/2009/04/03/shared-assembly-info-in-visual-studio-projects.aspx) to create a *SharedAssemblyInfo.cs* file at the solution level and linked to it from each of my projects.

The main point is that you want to add the *SharedAssemblyInfo.cs* file to your projects as a link. In Visual Studio, you would choose "Add Existing Item", but in the dialog, click the arrow on the Add button and select "Add As Link".

In *SharedAssemblyInfo.cs*, put any assembly attributes that you want to be the same across all projects. The article recommends the following:

- `AssemblyCompany`
- `AssemblyProduct`
- `AssemblyCopyright`
- `AssemblyTrademark`
- `AssemblyConfiguration`
- `AssemblyDescription`
- `CLSCompliant`
- `ComVisible`
- `AssemblyVersion`
- `AssemblyInformationalVersion`

Each project will still have its own *AssemblyInfo.cs* file as well to supplement the attribute it receives from the shared file:

- `AssemblyTitle`
- `AssemblyCulture`
- `Guid`

Comment: This is the approach I use and it works nicely once it's set up.

Comment: I use this in combination with [TeamCity's AssemblyInfo patcher](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/AssemblyInfo+Patcher).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using AssemblyInfo Task,

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/AssemblyInfoTaskvers

[Updated: it is an MSBuild targets from Microsoft MSBuild team. No Visual Studio addin is needed, so it works fine even if you use MSBuild directly.]

You can use its targets to modify a central AssemblyInfo.cs file and then link it to all projects. My open source project #SNMP shows how it is utilized,

https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib

Comment: Interesting - I'll look into that Lex

Answer (score 1):

Normally this should be only a comment, but I want to give this as an answer

This addin for VS is a  real lifesaver 
[Versioning Controlled Build](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5851/Versioning-Controlled-Build)

I'm so fond of this addin that I'm using it from the VS 2003 version.
Just pay attention and read all the article, there are some hiccups when other addins are installed

While the accepted answer is really good, I still prefer to have, for each project a separated assemblyinfo.cs, containing the **FileVersion** and **AssemblyVersion** attribute, because, in this way, I can increment these values separately, when there is a bug fix or a revision to distribute